# Failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Virtual Box in ubuntu 14.04 and I have settled a virtual machine(acs) but when I start the machine it gives me the following error.

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Hands-On-Ansible_acs_1467422605483_29306

Details

The virtual machine 'Hands-On-Ansible_acs_1467422605483_29306' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}